# Sound from both speakers and headphones with SoundMAX ADI AD1986A on Windows 7: possible?

Tags: windows-7, audio

My *ASUS A8N-VM CSM* motherboard has an on-board sound chip–the *SoundMAX ADI AD1986A*. Although sound does work reliably on Windows 7, I was a bit disappointed that neither ASUS nor the manufacturer of the sound chip offer drivers for it for Windows 7 (or Vista for that matter).
Among other things jack detection, output to front and rear jack simultaneously and surround sound are no longer available using Microsoft's default HD Audio driver under Windows 7.
Under Windows XP and several Linux distributions (Arch, Gentoo and Ubuntu) that I've tried everything works as it should.

Since I switch between headphones and speakers quite often, this annoyance begs me to ask: aside from buying a sound card, is there any way to get sound from both outputs at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching around, I found [this forum post](http://windows7forums.com/windows-7-support/19704-windows-7-asus-soundmax.html#post89043), which pointed me to the following driver download:
ftp://ftp.asus.com.tw/pub/asus/misc/audio/AD200B_6570_Win7.zip

It works great. Jack detection and surround are back, and although I'm now forced to have output on both front *and* rear jack, I'll pick that over going through going five clicks just to switch any day.

Comment: Any idea what to do on a HP laptop? I have the very same issue

Comment: Other than trying the linked driver, no. I can't test any other alternatives anymore since this motherboard has since died on me. Sorry I can't be more of help... @BujancaMihai

Comment: Could you please share with me how did you plug in the headphones and what settings did you use in soundmax esp?

Comment: @Pyjong Sadly, this computer suffered from an electrical overload several years back, so there is not much I can do about investigating at this point.